# How to access both/dual cameras simultaneously on android programatically in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-camera

In jetpack compose:

- Is it possible to access both cameras simultaneously?
- Can we use preview and do video recording and capture data of both cameras?